# Working abroad as a US citizen for a US university

Tags: us-citizens, netherlands, working, usa, contracts

My question is related to contracts when moving abroad as a US citizen working for a US organization (university). Starting September of this year I will be moving to the Netherlands and move in with my Dutch husband. My department wants me to continue working for them and also try to expand our relationships with European universities.

My question is as follows, do I need a special contract if I want to stay with them? Should they hire me as a freelancer perhaps? Or can I keep a "normal" US contract? Anybody here been in a similar situation that has some advice? Our HR department has no experience with this unfortunately so I am trying to collect information myself as well.

As a side note, I do have a working permit and residents permit for the Netherlands but would love to remain with my current employer. The Netherlands only seems to look at your world income and has a treaty with the US to prevent double taxation.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should probably add more info. Will the work only involve things happening in the US? Will you be paid in US Dollars? Into a US bank account? Do you expect to have other work in the Netherlands? What's your citizenship status in both states? etc.

Comment: If your university will be your employer, they should handle that. They have much more resources for that. Obviously you need a normal NL constact if you live in Netherlands.